# How do I export existing PowerPoint macros for importing onto other machines?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I have some macros created in Microsoft PowerPoint on my development machine. When the application is deployed, the macros are to be imported into the PowerPoint application in each machine in the network.

How can I export these macros, and how do I import these macros into a different machine's PowerPoint application?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Macros don't live in the PowerPoint application.  They either reside in PPT or PPTM files or in add-ins. In most cases you'll likely want to create an add-in from your code, then load it into each computer where it's required, either via the File | Add-Ins dialog box or using an installer app that makes the necessary registry entries to load the add-in automatically.